# Jsp servlet - login page is not redirecting properly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, authentication, web.xml

I am trying to create a login service but my pages are not redirecting properly. I have following:

login.jsp

```
<form action="login" method="post">

User Name
<br>
<input type="text" name="userId"/>
<br><br>
Password
<br>
<input type="password" name="password"/>
<br><br>
<input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

LoginServlet.java

```
package org.sohail.javabrains;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userId, password;

    userId=request.getParameter("userId");
    password=request.getParameter("password");

    LoginService loginService = new LoginService();

    boolean result = loginService.authenticate(userId, password);

    if (result) {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/success.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
    else {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        return;
    }
}

}
```

LoginService.java - has a authenticate(userId, password) method which connects to database, verifies userId and pass and returns a boolean value.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.sohail.javabrains.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

from login.jsp page, doesn't matter what I put I get following error:

HTTP Status 404 - /LoginApp/login

It should redirect the page to success.jsp if authenticate() reutrns true.

I am pretty new to this so please feel free to provide any other suggestions.

Comment: change your web.xml servlet mapping to <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping> 
and remove the WEB-INF part from your redirect url:
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp");

Comment: thanks! I didn't have to change WEB-INF/success.jsp though since success.jsp is in WEB_INF folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Birgit Martinelle for following answer:

change your web.xml servlet mapping to

```
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and remove the WEB-INF part from your redirect url:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp");
```

–  Birgit Martinelle 50 mins ago